# continue is not inside a loop, firebox gives compiler error, but chrome is fine about it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

```
function prototype(){

  for(var i in array){

    // insert prototype2 here
  }
}



function prototype2(){

  continue;

}
 // firefox throws error here

var finalFunction = combineFunctions(prototype, prototype2);
```

I am using functions as prototypes to build the final function.

Certain functions will eventually be copied inside loops, and they have continue statement. These prototype functions are not executed, but Firefox and other web browsers give error and stops the app.

Chrome and nodeJS are fine about it. What is the reason of that?
Is there anything i can do to make Firefox ignore these prototype functions?
Is Firefox going to adopt the chrome compiling algorithm?

Comment: It would help if you could post a sample of what you're talking about.  A `continue` statement is a syntax error if it is not nested in an iteration statement like `for` or `while`.

Comment: Node reports the syntax error but only when the function is *called*, which is a little strange.

Comment: You must be converting the function to a string when you use it to build other functions. Why not just store it as a string in the first place?

Comment: @Pointy The same thing with Chrome. Maybe it's because of JIT compilation.

Comment: In any case, this is invalid code. There's no reason to expect it to be acceptable to any JS implementation. The fact that Chrome and Node.js allow it is just dumb luck, you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if FF adopted the Chrome strategy -- they probably consider that to be a bug, and theirs to be superior.

Comment: i think we should be given the freedom to do these type of things... the code is not executed after all.

Comment: store it as a string is not very convenient for my project...

Comment: @AndréMarques Would you say the same thing about `if (something) { <syntax error here> }`, that it should be allowed if `something` is never true?

Comment: Well, surely it could lead to really hard debugging if it only tells us syntax errors when things are executed in if conditions... but i think we should have the options to do "virtual functions" which compiler ignores

Comment: What is it that you expect a `continue;` statement to even do if it's not in a loop? It's called out *explicitly* as a syntax error in the language spec, so that's pretty much that.

Comment: well, chrome throws the error only when it's executed and continue is not inside of the loop. I think it's fine to gives us certain liberty. After all JavaScript is supposed to be as dynamic as possible. Isn't any way to ignore certain syntax errors if i decide to? or i will not be able to run my app in firefox and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the language spec says:

> It is a Syntax Error if this production is not nested, directly or indirectly (but not crossing function boundaries), within an *IterationStatement*.

That some runtime (for the time being) allows that in a function that isn't called should not be relied upon; it could stop working with the next V8 update, and for all we know it may be caught even now in some situations.

It's OK to have ideas and opinions about what some particular programming language *should* do, but the way to act on those ideas is to get on the language design committee, or to choose a different language.  There are numerous alternative languages with mature, robust translation to JavaScript here in late 2018.

Comment: any idea on what i could do to avoid the error? How could i stringifiy for example: String(function(){ ... }) in such a way that it doesn't check errors?

Comment: Well it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve by putting the code into a function. How is that helping you? I mean, you can't actually *test* the function in any platform because of the syntax error, so what good does it do to have the code there at all?

Comment: So i built a engine to change objects, bind them and update them to client side in a simple way such as data.update("field1.field2.array", [1, 2, 3, "*5""]); and it happens to be that the algorithm (which loops though the data and executes the instructions) is the prototype of many many other functions. These final functions will end up with customized fragments of code within the original prototype function. This method i came up with is so dynamic and repetitive which makes making it manual impossible and the code would be huge and repetitive...

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do in the prototype2 function, which is contain loop continuation logic won't work because that function doesn't have any idea of the loop that it exists in.  It's pretty simple to show that this will error out in a small code sample - going to attach to illustrate the problem.

```js
function continueLoop() {
  continue;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) continueLoop();
  console.log(i);
}

/*
  Console will log:
    0
    1
    2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement
    at <anonymous>
*/

// NOTE:  You might need to paste this into your console to see the logs, this code-snippet environment seems to throw a different error, but Chrome console will give the 'Uncaught syntax error' - but I'm editing this in Safari and I see a different error when I run it in this editor, in a different browser.
```

Anyways, I'm not sure why you're trying to do that, but I don't see why it would work.